# Finding (sin(A+B))^2 given roots of a quadratic equation.

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

If tan A and tan B are the roots of the equation x^2 -ax + b = 0, then the value of sin(A+B)^2 is?

Options are:
((a^2)/((a^2)+(1-b)^2),

(a^2)/(a^2+b^2),

a^2/(b+a)^2,

a^2/(b^2*(1-a)^2)

The value is needed in terms of a and b. 
The farthest i have gotten is the sum of roots giving me:
(sinAcosB + CosAsinB)/CosAcosB = a
which simplifies to sin^2(A+B) = (a*cosA*cosB)^2
after which i substituted the value obtained from product of roots which was ((sinAsinB)/b)^2 = (CosACosB)^2 which is substituted again to obtain:

(a*SinA*sinB)^2/(b^2)

Please find the value with steps as i am very confused about this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, $\displaystyle\tan A+\tan B=\frac a1$ and $\displaystyle \tan A\tan B=\frac b1$

$\displaystyle\tan(A+B)=\frac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}$

$\displaystyle\sin^2(A+B)=\frac1{\csc^2(A+B)}=\frac1{1+\cot^2(A+B)}=\frac{\tan^2(A+B)}{\tan^2(A+B)+1}=\cdots$

Comment: I need the answer in terms of a and b (The coefficients of the quadratic equation. That is where i fail in derivation :/

Comment: @Mathbreaker, Please follow the steps in the answer?

Comment: Sorry, however, i am getting ((a^2)*cos(A+B))/(1-b)^2 = sin^2 (A+B)
I am not specifically good at these as i have just begun with the same, i am not entirely certain how to get a value of cos (A+B)

Comment: @Mathbreaker, How?

Comment: Well since tan(A+B) = (tana+tanb)/(1-tanatanb)
(a/1-b) = tan(A+B)
now sin(A+B) = (a/(1-b))*cos(A+B)
If we just square it i get sin(A+B) ^2 but it still has a cos(A+B) I need to eliminate. Not entirely sure how :/

Comment: Im sorry, i didn't read your final statement completely, thinking i could derive the answer from the hint provided. However, now that i have substituted the values from your final equation, i get the answer... Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Sum of roots; i.e., $\tan A + \tan B = $ -coefficient of $x /$ coefficient of $x^2 = a$

Product of roots; i.e., $\tan A \tan B = $ constant $/$ coefficient of $x^2 = b$

Now, $\tan (A+B)= \dfrac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 - \tan A \tan B} = \dfrac{a}{1-b}$

Draw a right triangle with opp side as $a$ and adjacent side as $1-b$.

So our hypotenuse will be $\sqrt{a^2 + (1-b)^2}$

$\sin(A+B)=$ opp/ hypotenuse $=\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + (1-b)^2}}$

So $\sin^2(A+B)= \dfrac{a^2}{a^2 + (1-b)^2}$

therefore, option A :-)